# Catching Future.failed error

Tags: scala

The following code prints `2`, but I was expecting (erroneously) `Future.failed` to act as a Java `throw new Exception` stopping any subsequent instructions (and captured by `recover`). How to make this code print "error msg"?

```
object HelloScala extends App {

      val f = futureFunction(1)
      f.map { result => println(result) }
      .recover { case e => println(e.getMessage) }


      def futureFunction (i:Int) =  {

            if (i==1) 
               Future.failed(new Throwable("error msg"))

           Future {2}
      }

      Thread.sleep(10000)
}
```

Comment: Without `else` you are creating the failed `Future` but not returning it. You throw it away and return the `Future(2)`. A `Future` isn't an exception that interrupts processing. It's like an `Option` in that it is a wrapper around a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `futureFunction` will always return `Future{2}`.  The following might serve what you need:

```
def futureFunction (i: Int) = {
  if (i==1) 
    Future.failed(new Throwable("error msg"))
  else
    Future.successful(2)
}
```